# How do i parse an Excel file with embeded images into a php array

Tags: php, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet with images which i need to upload to a db. How do i parse the spreadsheet into an array?

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ should be able to handle most of what you need.

Comment: For some reason even the example of this library doesn't work - says The filename example.xls is not readable

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) for parsing Excel files (though I am biased, as one of the developers). You don't mention which version of Excel (xls or xlsx files), but PHPExcel can read either... and it can read the images.

Reading the Excel worksheet data into a PHP array can be as simple as:

```
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';

$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray();
var_dump($sheetData);
```

**EDIT**

To extract images, use something like:

```
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("MyExcelFile.xls");

foreach ($objPHPExcel->getSheetByName("My Sheet")->getDrawingCollection() as $drawing) {
    if ($drawing instanceof PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing) {
        ob_start();
        call_user_func(
            $drawing->getRenderingFunction(),
            $drawing->getImageResource()
        );
        $imageContents = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    }
}
```

Comment: Phpexcel works fine however how to parse/identify an image because images are not placed in a cell.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114024/extracting-pictures-images-within-an-excel-file-xls-using-php?rq=1

Comment: Hi Mark after this can I just do something like                                                                $file = 'mynewimage.jpg';
file_put_contents($file, $imageContents);

Comment: @Alex - yes you can